# How to get the order in which the options were selected in an angular select?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am working with a form in Angular, using Angular Material. I need to get the order in which the options were selected in a select.

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection

I was testing with `selectionChange` but I did not find anything concerning the order in which the elements have been selected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which is the best option but you can send the event to the .ts file and with some JS make up logic to see which was chosen in which order first. #advice

Also it would help if you post some of your code to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I just don't really know where to start or how to do it.

Comment: Do you have any code at all?

1. Create a select dropdown
2. From the html, when select one of the options, you want to send a event to the .ts file
3. That way you can see what is selected, then make some logic and add each stuff into an array or something to see which order it came.

Try google 'How to send event with dropdown select'